# Show InfoWindow above another Dom Elements on Google Maps

Tags: css, google-maps, dom, google-maps-api-3, maps

I just started working with Google Maps API v3 and I'm using the map div alongside some other DOM elements showing above it by seting position aboslute and working with z-index.

My problem is I have to show the infoWindow of google maps that is generated inside de Map div above the  others DOM elements.

I'm not getting there. I also tried to put the DOM elements inside the Map div but it seems de API erases them.

Does anyone know what it could be done in order to infoWindow show above everything else?

Answer (score 0):

Use [custom overlay's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays) to place the elements on the map. The elements need to have `position` set to `fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [custom controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) instead of DOM elements to place on the map. The custom controls are placed above the map and when you open an InfoWindow, Google maps detects the position of the controls and automatically moves and opens the InfoWindow below the controls, so the both don't overlap. In this case it is better to use it instead of the [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow), because the overlay moves when you drag or zoom the map and the control always stays at the same position.